# Packagist: New releases from GitHub do not show up in Packagist

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

I have my own PHP/Composer repo on GitHub and have it published on packagist.org. Everything is fine so far. The Webservice is correctly configured and several versions have already been published.

But now I have the problem that when I try to publish a new version, it does not "end up" on packagist. Interestingly, packagist shows me (among older versions/tags) a version/tag "dev-master". After I pushed my latest changes to GitHub, created a tag/release on GitHub, and used "update" on the Packagist interface, this "dev-master" points to the latest commit on GitHub, but the new tag does not show up. Hence, when using `./composer update` in a project, nothing is updated at all.

Here is step-by-step what I do:

- Update and test my code.
- push it to the master branch of the repo at GitHub (master is the only branch here a.t.m.)
- update composer.json's "version" attribute to reflect the tag I am going to use for the next release
- create a new tag via the "draft new release" function in github (e.g. "5.6.7")
- go to packagist and click "update" in the repo.

Funny thing is, sometimes it works, sometimes not.

PS: Seems NOT to be an issue of delay. WHEN it worked, the new version was visible and installable within seconds. Otherwise, also waiting for several hours didnt fix the problem. Also, the hash of the latest commit from github is visible for "dev-master" immediately after I use "update" in Packagist.

Can anyone please tell be what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Did you solve this?

Comment: Not really. I wasnt able to locate the error. But it didnt show up for the last couple of releases for me following the exact steps listed above

Comment: I came across the same issue and it turned out that i just forgot to update the composer.json's version.. :-)